# calling ndk-build for echoPrint android sample

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, shazam

I'm getting this error after calling the ndk-build command in the cmd.
I followed the steps in this link http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2012/01/25/android-echoprint/

```
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `/codegen/src/Codegen.cpp', needed by `obj/
local/armeabi/objs/echoprint-jni//codegen/src/Codegen.o'.  Stop.
```

Can any one help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which platform the blog author used, and which version of NDK this was. But if you simply remove the heading "/" from the lines in **Android.mk** file, it should simply compile for you:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=AndroidCodegen.cpp \
        codegen/src/Codegen.cpp \
        codegen/src/Whitening.cpp \
        codegen/src/SubbandAnalysis.cpp \
        codegen/src/MatrixUtility.cpp \
        codegen/src/Fingerprint.cpp \
        codegen/src/Base64.cpp \
        codegen/src/AudioStreamInput.cpp \
        codegen/src/AudioBufferInput.cpp
```